# How to retrive full path of browse file in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How to get full files path of attached excel file in rails without any gem.

My view is

```
<%= form_for @hotel, :url => { :action => "create_by_excel_sheet" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :excel_sheet %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<%end%>
```

and when submit the form the attached excel file path I want to receive in create_by_excel_sheet action

I tried

`params["hotel"]["excel_sheet"].tempfile.path` then it return `"/tmp/RackMultipart20130921-3387-1ffc97o"` not a file path.

```
Ex: /file_path/file_name.file_extension
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it seems to me that you get really full path and it starts from your system root `/`. You can easy to check it.

I think it is logical to put not yet saved files (but already uploaded) to system temp folder.